UIViewControllerRepresentable Alert error in SwiftUI: Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property
there are errors on appear of Alert. I can not find how fix them. I need UIViewControllerRepresentable cause of alert deep customization.
First error: Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionViewCell that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing. View: <_UIAlertControllerTextFieldViewCollectionCell: 0x10e673530; frame = (0 0; 270 24); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000cc2190>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000002897c0>>
Second error: -[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID. inputModality = Keyboard, inputOperation = , customInfoType = UIEmojiSearchOperations
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sheetIsOpen = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Main View")
            Button("Open Sheet") {
                sheetIsOpen = true
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetIsOpen) {
            SheetWithAlert()
        }
    }
}

struct SheetWithAlert: View {
    @State private var isFirstResponder = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sheet With Alert")
            Button("Open Alert") {
                isFirstResponder = true
            }
        }
        .textFieldAlert(isFirstResponder: $isFirstResponder)
    }
}

extension View {
    func textFieldAlert(isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(TextFieldAlert(isFirstResponder: isFirstResponder))
    }
}

struct TextFieldAlert: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isFirstResponder: Bool
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(TextFieldAlertController(isFirstResponder: $isFirstResponder))
    }
}

struct TextFieldAlertController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isFirstResponder: Bool

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return UIViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        guard context.coordinator.alertController == nil else {return}

        if isFirstResponder {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Check email", message: "You are checking email.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            alertController.addTextField { textField in
                textField.delegate = context.coordinator
                textField.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
            
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
                self.isFirstResponder = false
                context.coordinator.alertController = nil
            })

            context.coordinator.alertController = alertController
            uiViewController.present(alertController, animated: true)
        } else if let alertController = context.coordinator.alertController {
            alertController.dismiss(animated: true) {
                context.coordinator.alertController = nil
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var alertController: UIAlertController?
        var parent: TextFieldAlertController

        init(_ parent: TextFieldAlertController) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
}

